# AJAX function is not working by scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

Using **AJAX** for endless scroll. Content loads only first time, but does't load by scroll.

What is wrong?

**jQuery:**

```
function loadFeed() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#posts").append('<div class="havanagila"></div>');
            $('#posts').html(data);
        }
    });
}

loadFeed();
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();

    if ((windowScroll + windowHeight) == documentHeight) {
        loadFeed();
    }
});
```

**loadmore.php:**

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ( isset( $_SESSION['login'] ) ) {

    $login    = $_SESSION['login'];
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];

    $username="root";
    $password="root";
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $dbname= "kotik";


    function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password){
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=kotik", $username, $password);
        return $dbh;
    }


    try {
        $dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}

?>

<?php                                                              

$title_select_query= $dbh -> prepare("SELECT title FROM books WHERE id = :id ORDER BY date DESC");
$title_select_query ->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
echo($title_select_query_result);

$title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
echo($title_select_query_result);

$title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
echo($title_select_query_result);

$title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
echo($title_select_query_result);

$title_select_query_result = $title_select_query->fetchColumn(); 
echo($title_select_query_result);

?>
```

Comment: You have an event handler inside a function that is being called inside the event handler. It just keeps adding up.

Comment: What does not work? Have you checked if the condition `if ((windowScroll + windowHeight) == documentHeight) {` really works?

Comment: There is no need to put `if` condition to load content every time using `AJAX`. Remove `if` condition it will load `AJAX` at scroll event.

Comment: @VInand, could you add the expected html result?

Comment: please check my answer and reply

Comment: He was asking for why the additional data is not added into the DOM. Then after that he asking for why same data is loaded. We thought that his PHP code just provides the sample data for AJAX call. And some guy gave him the whole run-able source code, then he choose that answer is the corrected one. I'll never appreciate that kind of answer as well as never support this kind of people who don't know exactly what he wants.

Comment: @Han you are absolutely right

Answer (score 13):

Because you replace the content of $('#posts'), the height of document does not change after first ajax request on scroll => so you need to scroll up , and then scroll down again to trigger  another ajax request.
Because i don't know the expected  page layout, i will give a simple basic demo
**HTML** [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/cchss5bc/1/)

```
<div id="main" style="height:200px; overflow-y : auto;">
    <div id="posts">
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var loadmoore = true,
    loaded_posts =0 ;
function gent_sample_data(num_posts){
    var i,
        sample_data = '';
    for(i=0;i<num_posts;i++) {
        sample_data += "<p class'post'>title_select_query_result " + (loaded_posts + i) + "</p>"; 
    }
    return sample_data;
}

function loadFeed(){
     // generate sample data
    var sample_data = gent_sample_data(15);
    loaded_posts = loaded_posts + 15;
    $.ajax({
        url : '/echo/html/',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'post',
        data: {'html':sample_data},
        success: function(returnhtml){
            console.log(returnhtml);
             // option 1 - add result into "havanaglia" div
            // var $post = $('<div class="havanagila"></div>');
            // $post.html(returnhtml);
            // $("#posts").append($post);

            // option 2 - ad result after "havanaglia" div
            $("#posts").append('<div class="havanagila"></div>');
            $("#posts").append(returnhtml); 
            loadmoore = true;
        }    
    });
}
loadFeed();

$("#main").scroll(function () { 
    if (loadmoore && $("main").scrollTop() >= ($("main").height()-100) ) {
       loadmoore = false;
       loadFeed();
    }
});
```

For your case I suggest  to use something like this:

```
var loadmoore= true;
function loadFeed() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            var $havanaglia = $('<div class="havanagila"></div>');
            $havanaglia.html(data);
            $("#posts").append($havanaglia);
            loadmoore = true;
        }
    });
}

loadFeed();

$(window).scroll(function () { 
    if (loadmoore && $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()-100) {
        loadmoore= false;
       loadFeed();
    }
});
```

To prevent to get the same posts from database i recommend to send to php the id/number of last loaded post to get posts with id/number > last loaded post

Comment: @vasilenicusor  it scrolls, but it just loads that data two times, like 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Exactly, first time load only on page load and second time when you scroll down. Because the height of document are not increased ( you replace the existing posts with the new posts). If you want to don't keep the  existing post and to load data more than two time, after data is loaded you must change the scroll position to 0 or to a position where  $(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()-$(window).height()-100 is FALSE. Another fix to your code is to tell to php script how many post you want and from which position  e.g.SELECT title FROM books WHERE id= :id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,5

Answer (score 6):

If you want to load `AJAX` function for each scroll event there is no need to check `if` condition. simply write..

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        loadFeed();
});
```

and if you want to call the `AJAX` function if the scroll has reached the bottom you have to check condition like...

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        loadFeed();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

change you `loadFeed()` funtion to this

```
function loadFeed() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#posts").append('<div class="havanagila"></div>');
            $('#posts').html($('#posts').html()+data);
        }
    });
}
```

this is the change you have to do `$('#posts').html($('#posts').html()+data);`

Comment: @VarunHaharia didn't help. I suggest that the problem is partially in php file.

Comment: if you'll be able to provide the database table from where it fetches data I am sure I will provide you solution with 30-40 min, I simply don't want make a table first and fill it with data to test the code

Answer (score 5):

If I remember correctly I was suffering the same problem for something similar. What I did was to stop the scroll listener and restart it upon AJAX success.

Here's the code that could help you:

```js
function loadFeed() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#posts").append('<div class="havanagila"></div>');
            $('#posts').html(data);
            $(window).on('scroll', function() {checkScroll()}); // Run the function again upon success
        }
    });
}

var checkScroll = function() {
  if ($('#SomeElementAlwaysAtTheBottomOfThePage')[0]) {
    var el = $('#SomeElementAlwaysAtTheBottomOfThePage');
    var bottom_of_object = el.offset().top + el.outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if (bottom_of_window >= bottom_of_object) { // If we're at the bottom...
      $(window).unbind('scroll'); // Stop the scroll function
      loadFeed(); // Load the AJAX
    }
  }
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {checkScroll()}); // Start the function off
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="posts"></div>
<div id="SomeElementAlwaysAtTheBottomOfThePage"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you overwrote the inner content of element `#posts` by `html()` function.
`$("#posts").append('<div class="havanagila"></div>');
 $('#posts').html(data);`

I think you want
`$("#posts").append($('<div class="havanagila"></div>').html(data));`

And about your IF statement `if ((windowScroll + windowHeight) == documentHeight)`, your ajax function is called only if you scroll from the top to the bottom of the page (on Chrome).

Answer (score 2):

The following javascript code is used to load 4 records when the scroll bar hit at the bottom of screen. That means when first time 4 records will fetched, second time next 4 records fetched and these all records will displayed on the screen. This code help us to decrease the load lag at page load time.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       //alert("bottom!");
       loadNext();
   }
});
var n1=0;
var n2=4;

function loadFirst()
{
    var n1=0;
    var n2=4;   
}
function loadNext()
{
    n1=n1+4;
    n2=n2+4;
    //alert(n1);    
    //alert(n2);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("testidiv").innerHTML=document.getElementById("testidiv").innerHTML+xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","next_testimonial_action.php?a=" + n1 + "&b=" + n2,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}


</script>
```

"next_testimonial_action.php?a=" + n1 + "&b=" + n2" is the php page that contains logic for fetching data from db, and n1,n2 are the limit of the records to be fetched. If you need the php file you can request as a comment. Thank you

---- Important---- "You must call loadFirst() function at bodyOnload or document.ready() jquery"

Answer (score 0):

Everything look fine to me,

Just Change `$(window).scroll(function () {......` to

```
$(document).on( 'scroll','window', function(){
              //or $(document).on( 'scroll','id of div containing scroll',
   var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   var documentHeight = $(document).height();

    if ((windowScroll + windowHeight) == documentHeight) {
         loadFeed();
       }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function loadFeed() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#posts").append('<div class="havanagila"></div>');
            $('#posts').html(data);
            $(window).on('scroll', function() {checkScroll()}); // Run the function again upon success
        }
    });
}

var checkScroll = function() {
  if ($('#SomeElementAlwaysAtTheBottomOfThePage')[0]) {
    var el = $('#SomeElementAlwaysAtTheBottomOfThePage');
    var bottom_of_object = el.offset().top + el.outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if (bottom_of_window >= bottom_of_object) { // If we're at the bottom...
      $(window).unbind('scroll'); // Stop the scroll function
      loadFeed(); // Load the AJAX
    }
  }
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {checkScroll()}); // Start the function off
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="posts"></div>
<div id="SomeElementAlwaysAtTheBottomOfThePage"></div>
```