# How to have an action respond to javascript in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails, kohana

I'm currently working with a Kohana project and am trying to implement endless scrolling. I'm trying to use the method Ryan Bates shows in the following Ruby on Rails video:

https://youtu.be/PQX2fgB6y10?t=2m29s

At 3:21 he says the action won't respond to javascript and proceeds to create a js.erb file. What is the PHP equivalent to this step going forward? Where would I place the php file equivalent to his index.js.erb?

Comment: Think it would be equivalent to a .php script which renders html.  Some frameworks use thinks like .phtml (really just PHP with html... i.e templating).  Some fraemworks have things like 'view helpers',  Seems to be you just want your JS code to make a call and receive a portion of HTML back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy what he did, just create a PHP file that generates Javascript with the content you want to append like he did with `render()`. You can call this file whatever you want, but following his convention, it would be `index.js.php`.

So for example:

```
$('#products').append('<?php render_elements(); ?>');
$('#pagination').replaceWith('<?php render_pagination(); ?>');
```

Since you're already this far in his tutorial, I assume that you have the code to render the elements you want to display already.

---

It may be easier however to use [other AJAX methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001920/ajax-function-is-not-working-by-scroll) to achieve the same thing though.

Comment: I did however find a plugin that did exactly what I wanted to do with existing pagination in place. However I didn't want to pay for commercial use so I just went and figured out how to use AJAX instead. This is the plugin for anyone who doesn't want to use the AJAX way: http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/download.html